# Compatibility between void * and char *

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c99, void-pointers

Are void and char pointer guaranteed to have the same memory representation?

In other words, after executing the following:

```
char a = 'z';
void *b = &a;
char *c;

memcpy(&c, &b, sizeof(b));
```

Can I be certain that `*c == 'z'` (there is no undefined behavior, etc.)?

Comment: you haven't allocated any memory for the `*c`

Comment: @DanielA.White I don't need to, it points to a. If I do, that would be a memory leak

Comment: @DanielA.White The `memcpy` sets `c`.  The undefined pointer value is never used.  Note the `&` operator.  Your comment would be valid if the `&` were absent.

Comment: There are no undefined values here, the memcpy() basically does c = b.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, according to the [C99 standard (ISO/IEC 9899)](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section §6.2.5 point 27:

> A pointer to `void` shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a
> pointer to a character type.<sup>39)</sup>
>
> <sup>39) The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions, return values from functions, and members of unions.</sup>